# MPMoviePlayerController and custom controls iOS8

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8, uigesturerecognizer, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
- (UIView*)getContainerView
{
    UIView *playerControls = (self.videoPlayer.view ? self.videoPlayer.view : self.view);

    NSString* containerViewName = [self getContainerViewName]; **//@"MPSwipableView" gets returned**
    for(UIWindow* tempWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication]windows]){
        for(UIView* tempView in [tempWindow subviews]){
            if ([[tempView description] rangeOfString:containerViewName].location != NSNotFound){
                playerControls = tempView;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(playerControls == nil){
        NSLog(@"player ERROR : movieDidEnterFullScreen , no view named %@ was found",containerViewName);
    }
    return playerControls;
}

- (void)addCustomControls
{
//...//

UIView *controlsPlaceholder = [self getContainerView];
    if (controlsPlaceholder) {
        if (![controlsPlaceholder.subviews containsObject:self.customControls.view]) {
            [controlsPlaceholder addSubview:self.customControls.view];
        }else{
            [controlsPlaceholder bringSubviewToFront:self.customControls.view];
        }
    }
//...//
    if (self.tapGestureRecognizer == nil) {
        self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
        self.tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
    if ([Device] is_iPad]) {
        [self.customControls.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
    }
    else {
        [self.videoPlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

===================

My problem is only with iOS8 while the player is in fullscreen. The handleTapGesture: is not called and also when I go in fullscreen the custom controls view disappears.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "getContainerViewName" method has the following change:

```
- (NSString*)getContainerViewName
{
    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iOS5]) {
        return @"UILayoutContainerView";
    }
    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iOS6]) {
        return @"MPSwipableView";
    }
    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iOS7]) {
        return @"MPSwipableView";
    }
    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iOS8]) {
        return@"MPSwipableView";
    }
    NSLog(@"player ERROR : getContainerViewName");
    return nil;
}

- (NSString*)getContainerViewName
{
    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iOS5]) {
        return @"UILayoutContainerView";
    }
    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iOS6]) {
        return @"MPSwipableView";
    }
    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iOS7]) {
        return @"MPSwipableView";
    }
    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iOS8]) {
        if (self.playerIsInfullScreen) {
            return @"UIInputSetContainerView";
        }else {
            return@"MPSwipableView";
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"player ERROR : getContainerViewName");
    return nil;
}
```

The custom controls view will respond to touch and it will also be visible. Hopefully this will help someone in need.

Comment: Thanks @Drd, this has helped me climb out of an MPMoviePlayerController-shaped pit of despair :)